# Using a sub-query inside a View causes SSMS to show an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, view, subquery

I am dealing with a huge stored procedure which works but is a little ungainly and am attempting to retire this and use a view instead.

I have the following SQL generated by SSMS' View designer

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Trip.Title AS Heading,
    dbo.Trip.Description, 
    dbo.Trip.TripLengthDays AS DayAmount, 
    dbo.TripDetail.PriceTo, 
    dbo.City.Name AS CityName, 
    dbo.Country.Name AS CountryName
FROM
    dbo.Trip 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TripDetail ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripDetail.TripID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TripCity ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripCity.TripID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.City ON dbo.TripCity.CityID = dbo.City.ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Country ON dbo.City.CountryID = dbo.Country.ID
```

I've truncated it a little for clarity.

When I move over the SQL to generate an XML string the designer gets upset when I pass it this...

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Trip.Title AS Heading,
    dbo.Trip.Description, 
    dbo.Trip.TripLengthDays AS DayAmount, 
    dbo.TripDetail.PriceTo, 
    dbo.City.Name AS CityName, 
    dbo.Country.Name AS CountryName,
    (SELECT e.Id, e.Name AS [ActivityName]
     FROM [dbo].[MyDatabase] e
     INNER JOIN [trip].[ActivityLookup] l ON l.ActivityId = e.Id
     WHERE Trip.id = l.TripId
     FOR XML PATH('Activity'), ROOT('Activities')) AS ActivitiesJson
FROM            
    dbo.Trip 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TripDetail ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripDetail.TripID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TripCity ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripCity.TripID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.City ON dbo.TripCity.CityID = dbo.City.ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Country ON dbo.City.CountryID = dbo.Country.ID
```

[image: SSMMS Alert box]

Given that this same block of SQL works outside of the designer I am wondering if there's anything I specifically need to do to get the view to return this string in the same way that the stored procedure does?

Comment: Don't use the designer. It's flawed at best, and it's support for syntax is limited; as you have experienced. Also, [3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). Alias your objects and use those to qualify your columns.

Comment: Regardless of what the "designer" says - what happens when you execute the sql directly in SSMS? Sometimes the designer just can't cope - personally I have never used it, it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Larnu This is the SQL that the designer generates. TBH I didn't know it was deprecated, but I'll certainly take your advice going forward.

Comment: @Stu Actually the SQL will execute. I'm using the designer because it's easy (When it works) and I'm not used to using Views yet.

Comment: @Andrew the subquery you have used in the select list, you are projecting two columns, It should be one column. SELECT e.Id, e.Name AS [ActivityName]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using an in-line subquery with more than one column: e.Id and e.Name are two separate columns and you want to include them both in your view with one column name: "ActivitiesJson"

If you want them both added together to form one field, then use the plus sign to join them:

```
SELECT e.Id + e.Name AS [ActivityName]
```

Or if e.Id is an integer and e.Name is a varchar, something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(e.Id AS varchar(100)) + e.Name AS [ActivityName]
```

Comment: But with `FOR XML` there is only one result, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=560f625d087b5c9384678a5396042707 so this is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your subquery into an `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Trip.Title AS Heading,
    dbo.Trip.Description, 
    dbo.Trip.TripLengthDays AS DayAmount, 
    dbo.TripDetail.PriceTo, 
    dbo.City.Name AS CityName, 
    dbo.Country.Name AS CountryName,
    Activities.[Json] AS ActivitiesJson
FROM            
    dbo.Trip 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TripDetail ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripDetail.TripID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TripCity ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripCity.TripID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.City ON dbo.TripCity.CityID = dbo.City.ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Country ON dbo.City.CountryID = dbo.Country.ID
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT (
    
        SELECT 
            e.Id, e.[Name] AS [ActivityName]
        FROM [dbo].[MyDatabase] e
        INNER JOIN [trip].[ActivityLookup] l ON l.ActivityId = e.Id
        WHERE 
            e.Trip.id = l.TripId
        FOR XML PATH('Activity'), ROOT('Activities')
    
    ) AS [Json]

) AS Activities
```

I am a little confused as to why you are naming your XML as JSON, however.

Comment: Hah the JSON naming is a holdover from when it was originally created on the the Staging SQL server which is 2016. The live is 2012. So it had to be converted to XML so that it would work on the older server!
I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't actually produce any results and the designer still displayed the same error. I need to read up on OUTER APPLY though as I'm not familiar with it.